# How can I view Paradox database files with Arabic characters?

Tags: database, unicode, paradox

I want to read a database which contains Arabic characters. I want to convert it to SQL or Access. I tried "Paradox dBase Access Reader" using UTF-8 character set but the database is not readable. The database is very old and is created using Paradox 5.0 for Windows. It is not password protected.

Answer (score 0):

The old Paradox databases uses "Character pages" to display the character set in Arabic and others. This was different than UTF (I believe). These were often referred to as DOS character sets, and were not unique to Paradox. Try to find the Paradox page for Arabic. This configuration was usually set up in a Paradox configuration file. I'm not sure if Access can handle these character pages, although I think it could at one time.